# Add the last appearance to table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables (for example)
table1 will contain stores, there are 2 types 'candy store' and 'dental store'.
Each row contains information about a customer's purchase in a particular store

table1 ( purchases ):

```
+----+---------+------------------+-------+
| id | store   | date of purchase | money |
| 1  | store 1 | 2016-01-01       | 10    |
| 1  | store 5 | 2018-01-01       | 50    |
| 2  | store 2 | 2017-01-20       | 10    |
| 2  | store 3 | 2019-02-20       | 15    |
| 3  | store 2 | 2017-02-02       | 20    |
| 3  | store 6 | 2019-01-01       | 60    |
| 1  | store 1 | 2015-01-01       | 20    |
+----+---------+------------------+-------+
```

table2 ( type ):

```
+---------+--------+
| store   | type   |
| store 1 | candy  |
| store 2 | candy  |
| store 3 | candy  |
| store 4 | dental |
| store 5 | dental |
| store 6 | dental |
+---------+--------+
```

I want my query to return a table like this:

```
+----+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
| id | the last place| the last date c |the last date d|
| 1  | store 5       | 2016-01-01      |  2018-01-01   |
| 2  | store 3       | 2019-02-20      |  -            |
| 3  | store 6       | 2017-02-02      |  2019-01-01   |
+----+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

where

- [the last place] is the last store where client bought smth;
- [the last date c] - the last date of buying in candy's shop
- [the last date d] is the last date of buying in dental shop

and delete rows if no any matches(all values are null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and `join`:

```
select t1.id,
       (array_agg(store order by t1.date_of_purchase desc))[1] as last_store,
       max(t1.date_of_purchase) filter (where t2.type = 'candy') as last_candy,
       max(t1.date_of_purchase) filter (where t2.type = 'dental') as last_dental
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     using (store)
group by t1.id;
```

Comment: how it returns the last store by purchase?

Comment: @Qugean . . . Oops, I missed that.  I updated the answer.

Comment: @Qugean . . . I fixed the typo.  It was returning the first store rather than the last one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `group by`,`max` and `window function` in postgresql :

```
select id
,max(case when rnb=1 then store else null end) the_last_place
,max(case when type='candy' then date else null end) the_last_date_c
,max(case when type='dental' then date else null end) the_last_date_d
 from(
    select t1.id,t1.store,t1.date,row_number() over(partition by t1.id order by t1.date desc) rnb
    from table1 t1 
    inner join table2 t2 
    on t1.store=t2.store
    ) t
group by id ;
```

Comment: your request returns the correct stores but not the date(date is null )

Comment: also good solution, but you missed field "type" , it should be like 
max(case when type='candy' then date else null end) the_last_date_c
,max(case when type='dental' then date else null end) the_last_date_d 

and in from (  select....., type, ....            )

Comment: o,it was a mistake 'type' to replace 'store',I have correct it.